# order approval for magento

Tags: magento

I ’m in need of setting up approvers for orders that customers submit.

There is no credit card authorization required. For example, an employee from a company puts foo and bar into their shopping cart and checks out. One of the employee’s bosses need to approve it (the superiors will have accounts in magento already) before they can be invoiced. So when an order is placed, an email needs to go to the bosses, with a URL to the order. Then they can accept it or decline it.

Is there an existing extension that does something like this or would be a good starting point?

Answer (score 3):

Yep, there is. :)

Check out the free [ZetaPrints Order Approval](http://www.zetaprints.com/magentohelp/magento-order-approval/) extension. I have experience with it and it does exactly what you want. ;)